# Cordova / Phonegap downloading a lot of images, best possible solution

Tags: image, cordova, download, ionic-framework

I need some advice.
I have Phonegap / Cordova content app created using Ionic Framework.
This app is supose to work both offline and online.

So far I managed to implement offline database (SQLite), but I have some trouble with images.

The first strategy I chose was to "install" all the images at the beginning of first start of app (in meanwhile Progress Bar was visible)

It works, but I think that first start of app is simply too slow (it's over 800 images)
It takes more than 7 minutes, which is really bad for user experience.

Here are some of my strategies:

- Download all the images as single ZIP file and extract it into device
- Download only some part of images (25% ?) and then download rest of them in the background, while user can use his app. Use some kind of images placeholder at some places ?

Which strategy is the best ?
Maybe someone has similar experience ?

Answer (score 0):

**[image-saver](https://github.com/promactkaran/image-saver)**

An Ionic/Angular directive for **saving remote images to local file storage**. Might be able to help you out. Make sure to follow the readMe.md file.