# iOS downloading a lot of images, best possible solution

Tags: ios, xcode, image, download

Some time ago I posted this question:
[Cordova / Phonegap downloading a lot of images, best possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344043/cordova-phonegap-downloading-a-lot-of-images-best-possible-solution)

But no one really answered that.

I decided to do same application, but in Objective C for now.
But I still have same problem :)

So, I have iOS app developerd using Objective C and XCode.
This app is suppose to work both offline and online.
If user is launching app for the first time, he sees progress bar and all the data and images are fetched and downloaded to his device.
After that process app is reloading (starting again)

It works, but I think that first start of app is simply too slow (it's over 800 images) It takes more than 7 minutes, which is really bad for user experience.

Here are some of my strategies:

- Download all the images as single ZIP file and extract it into device
- Download only some part of images (25% ?) and then download rest of them in the background, while user can use his app. Use some kind of images placeholder at some places ?

Which strategy is the best ? Maybe someone has similar experience ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step : 1**

I'll suggest you to not to download the images first time. Just pull your required data and feed your database or what ever technique you are using and let the use go inside the application. Which should take hardly few seconds.

**Step : 2**

Download only those images which are currently needs to show. And remember don't download the image on main thread. And after download save them in local folder. So that you don't need to download the same image again. As your application support offline mode so you can use a place holder image if the image is not get downloaded earlier.

**Setp : 3**

Before start downloading an image first check whether it's exists or not in your local folder.

To download an image you can go through the below link.

1. [Download an image and save it](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/)
2. [download and create an image from a url](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/download-and-create-an-image-from-a-url.html)
3. [iOS async image download](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/iOS-Async-Image-Downloader)

Answer (score 0):

You should download images only when you are going to display it. I think easiest way is to use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. It will load images for you, cache it, clear cache if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You already got some good answers.

And your idea of downloading just some of them at the beginning is good too.

I would suggest you use a hybrid approach.

When the app start you check what images you have and start downloading the rest on a background thread with low priority so the app would work fine.

Also you open the app normally and every time you need to show an image you check if you have it, and if not you download it right away. It should be pretty fast to get just one.

You didn't give us too many details about you app, but you could also just bundle all the images in the app if they don't change at all. And have a good description to the app so the user would know why the app si so big.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. I did the program-catalog and I had to download a lot of images with first app start. I decided to upload all images via first run, rather than load them dynamically, because the program should work in offline mode. I did that via [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)  `pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"`.

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>


NSMutableArray *imageURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //URLs to your images
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];

NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                          (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableArray *operations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<imageURLs.count; i++){
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLs[i]]];
    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSString *filePath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourImageName.png"];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"Image downloaded");
    }];
    [operations addObject:operation];

}
[operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```